# Where can Stirling's Approximation be used?

Tags: calculus, integration

I recently came across the Stirling's Approximation while learning Gamma function, which says $n! \approx \sqrt {2\pi} n^{n+\frac{1}{2}} e^{-n}$ and I was wondering where this approximation can be used?

Also I wanted to learn whether the proof of $\Gamma(n) = \frac{1}{n} \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1+\frac{1}{k})^n}{(1+\frac{n}{k})}$ involves the above approximation.

Comment: Stirling's formula is $n! \sim \sqrt {2\pi n} \left ( \frac{n}{e}\right)^n$, when $n\to\infty$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation . It is approximation, not equality.

Comment: It is used a lot in [**Fundamentals of Statistical and Thermal Physics**](https://archive.org/details/fundamentalsofst00fred) by Frederick Rief (1965; see Appendix A $\cdot$ 6, pp. 610-614), the book used for a statistical mechanics course I took in Fall 1981.

Comment: There are as many applications as there are cases where one wants an approximation of factorial function, i.e., there are many many of them ; see references [here](https://arpita95b.medium.com/stirlings-approximation-a-powerful-tool-to-approximate-factorials-bcad5089e658) for instance.

Comment: @User0 : Check out the better approximation $$n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n}\left(\dfrac{n}{e} +\dfrac{1}{12 e n}\right)^n$$

Comment: In data structures and algorithms, it is often used as an easy proof that sorting an array requires $\Omega(n\log(n))$ comparisons.

Comment: There is a fairly convenient version of Stirling's approximation that can be used for any positive integer $n$, which is $\sqrt{2\pi} n^{n+1/2} e^{-n} < n! \leq e n^{n+1/2} e^{-n}$. (In fact, $\frac{n! e^n}{n^{n+1/2}}$ goes monotonically down from $e$ to $\sqrt{2\pi}$ as $n$ increases past $1$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(i)$ For instance, the probability $\mathsf{P}_n$ that a simple random walk in one dimension returns to the origin after $2n$ steps is
$$\mathsf{P}_n=\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n}.$$
Using Stirling's approximation,
$$\mathsf{P}_n\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}},$$
which provides a better understanding of the magnitude of the probability $\mathsf{P}_n$.

$(ii)$ Stirling's formula is used in deriving the [De Moivre–Laplace theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem), which is a more general statement than the one I provided above.

$(iii)$ [The asymptotic expansion of the exponential integral](http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.12.i) $E_1(x)$ may be written as
$$
E_1 (x) = \frac{{{\rm e}^{-x} }}{x}\left( {1 - \frac{{1!}}{x} + \frac{{2!}}{{x^2 }} - \ldots  + \theta _n  \cdot ( - 1)^n \frac{{n!}}{{x^n }}} \right)
$$
for any $x>0$, $n\ge 0$ and with a suitable $0<\theta_n<1$. Taking ratios of successive terms reveals that, for fixed large $x$, the least term occurs around $n\approx x$. What is the size of the error term in that case? Stirling's formula tells us that
$$
\left| {\theta _n  \cdot ( - 1)^n \frac{{n!}}{{x^n }}} \right| \le \frac{{n!}}{{x^n }} \sim \frac{{x!}}{{x^x }} \sim \frac{{\sqrt {2\pi } x^{x + 1/2} {\rm e}^{ - x} }}{{x^x }} = \sqrt {2\pi x} \,{\rm e}^{ - x} ,
$$
i.e., the error term is exponentially small as a function of $x$.

$(iv)$ Stirling's approximation is the leading term of [a complete asymptotic expansion](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.i) for the gamma function:
$$
\Gamma (z + 1) \sim \sqrt {2\pi } z^{z + 1/2} {\rm e}^{ - z} \left( {1 + \frac{1}{{12z}} + \frac{1}{{288z^2 }} -  \ldots } \right)
$$
as $z\to \infty$ in sectors of the form $|\arg z|\le \pi-\delta<\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

It's frequently applied in the theory of Riemann's $\zeta$-function. By analytic continuation, it is proven that

$$
\zeta(s)=2^s\pi^{s-1}\sin\left(\pi s\over2\right)\Gamma(1-s)\zeta(1-s).
$$

Let $N(T)$ be the number of zeros of $\zeta(s)$ such that $0\le\beta\le1$, $0<\gamma\le T$, and $s=\beta+i\gamma$. Then through Stirling's approximation, one has

$$
N(T)={T\over2\pi}\log{T\over2\pi}-{T\over2\pi}+O(\log T).
$$

This is known as [Riemann-von Mangoldt formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93von_Mangoldt_formula).